# Unable to pass value of this operator in IE 9 while it is working fine in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Am unable to use attributes of div tag by passing object to loadApp()  using this operator

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<script>
function loadApp(theItem)
{
_thePage = theItem.appname;
alert(_thePage);// displaying undefined value in IE 9 while it works in IE7 and IE8(../eisptool.html)
}
</script>
</head>
```

in body we have a div tag with following attributes:

```
<div class="treeItem" onclick="setGroup('graph');loadApp(this)" fex="GSAS"   appname="../eisptool.html" show="domainView calculationRule target" hide="trigger">Summary Graph</div>
```

When am trying to use appname attribute of div tag am getting undefined value .

Comment: I'm surprised it works in IE7 and IE8. Custom HTML attributes are usually not added to the DOM element as properties. IE9 behaves correctly here.

Answer (score 1):

Some attributes are automatically turned into properties by the browser such as `.id`.  But, custom attributes are generally not turned into properties so if you want to read a custom attribute in all browsers, you need to read it with `.getAttribute()`.

```
function loadApp(theItem) {
    _thePage = theItem.getAttribute("appname");
    alert(_thePage);
}
```

Of course, you really should be using the HTML5 spec for custom attributes and use the `data-` prefix so the custom attribute in your HTML would be `data-appname="../eisptool.html"` and you'd use `getAttribute("data-appname")`.